# Python, tweepy stream

Tags: python, twitter, stream, tweepy

I am using code similar to the one below, from: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/blob/master/examples/streaming.py

The API allows you track multiple filter terms, in this example track=['usa','canada']. This essentially means that the stream will be collecting tweets that mention either 'canada' or 'usa'.

The issue is that the function on_data() prints the data, but it does not specify which filter term the data belongs to. when you only filter by one term such as in the sample provided on the github page then its implicit, but when you have multiple terms how can you print both the term and the data associated to it?

In other words how do I know which tweets were filtered by 'canada' and which by 'usa'?

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, print_function

from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

# Go to http://apps.twitter.com and create an app.
# The consumer key and secret will be generated for you after
consumer_key=""
consumer_secret=""

# After the step above, you will be redirected to your app's page.
# Create an access token under the the "Your access token" section
access_token=""
access_token_secret=""

class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    """ A listener handles tweets that are received from the stream.
    This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
    """
    def on_data(self, data):
        print(data)
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

    stream = Stream(auth, l)
stream.filter(track=['usa','canada'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the third possibility: that a tweet matched *both* "canada" and "usa". Still, the solution is simply to test if either or both filter words are present in the tweet. So:

```
def on_data(self, data):
    text = data.text.lower()
    if "canada" in text:
        do_canada()
    if "usa" in text:
        do_usa()
    return True
```